# Pass first textbox value for each row when delete button is click from generated grid to the JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

[image]I've generated a HTML table(grid) to display the data such as the Package Name, Package Cost, and the No. of Attendees from the database (if it has a data). 
Each field has a textbox to display it's content. 
For each row there is a delete button to remove the row.
When the user click the delete button the Package Name should be pass to the dialog and display the Package Name on it.
Please help me on how to do this?

Comment: I've tried this one $(this).closest('tr').find('input')[1].attributes[1] but no good. I will upload the image so that you will have an idea

Comment: I need to find the Package Name text box to get the value of the current row that I want to delete.

Comment: try something like `$(this).closest('tr').find('input:eq(0)').val()`

Comment: thanks ahren, it works. just put it as answer for me to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual HTML is a bit hard but you can use something like this in your button click event:

```
var name = $(this).parent().find('input:eq(0)').val(); //get the name
$(this).parent().remove(); //remove row
```